# Magento 2 plugin not working for CommonTaxCollector model

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, tax, plugin

I want to overwrite **mapItem** function which is under the **CommonTaxCollector** class. So, I have done this but getting undefined error.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory::getTaxCalculationItemId() in /app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/CommonTaxCollectorPlugin.php:14
```

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector">
        <plugin name="[vendorname]_[modulename]_commontaxcollector" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\CommonTaxCollectorPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/CommonTaxCollectorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin;

class CommonTaxCollectorPlugin
{
    public function aroundMapItem(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\CommonTaxCollector $subject,
        $itemDataObjectFactory,
        $item,
        $priceIncludesTax,
        $useBaseCurrency,
        $parentCode = null        
    ) {
        if (!$item->getTaxCalculationItemId()) {
            $sequence = 'sequence-' . $this->getNextIncrement();
            $item->setTaxCalculationItemId($sequence);
        }

        $itemDataObject = $itemDataObjectFactory->create();
        $itemDataObject->setCode($item->getTaxCalculationItemId())
            ->setQuantity($item->getQty())
            ->setTaxClassKey(
                $this->taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory->create()
                    ->setType(TaxClassKeyInterface::TYPE_ID)
                    ->setValue($item->getProduct()->getTaxClassId())
            )
            ->setIsTaxIncluded($priceIncludesTax)
            ->setType(self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT);

        if ($useBaseCurrency) {
            if (!$item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice()) {
                $item->setBaseTaxCalculationPrice($item->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal());
            }
            $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getBaseTaxCalculationPrice())
                ->setDiscountAmount($item->getBaseDiscountAmount());
        } else {
            if (!$item->getTaxCalculationPrice()) {
                $item->setTaxCalculationPrice($item->getCalculationPriceOriginal());
            }
            $itemDataObject->setUnitPrice($item->getTaxCalculationPrice())
                ->setDiscountAmount($item->getDiscountAmount());
        }


        return $itemDataObject;
    }
}
```

Thank you,